# capture a value of a form asp.net and make it accessible in every page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I have a value that I can only capture in javascript when I be on a specific "My Data "page/tab when logged in.

> var idMail =
>   document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_txtEmail').value

I think I need to load the content or part of it of the form that gets its data from the server but on every page/tab.
Is there a way to achive this in javascript?

Best Regards
Guy

Comment: Either save it locally (localStorage, cookie, etc) or fetch it from the server on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following -

- Hidden Form Fields ,Query Strings, UrlData, Cookies ,Session Variables,
  Application Variables, Cache

As per me using  Application Variables will be best global.aspx. See this - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx